# Generalizing a Trigonometric Infinite Product of Vieta

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-product

The second exercise in "[Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis and Number Theory](http://www.gibbs.if.usp.br/~marchett/estocastica/MarkKac-Statistical-Independence.pdf)," by Mark Kac is to prove that $$
{\sin x\over x}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac13\left(1+2\cos{2x\over3^k}\right)\tag{1}
$$ 
and generalize it.  This is a generalization of Vieta's formula $$
{\sin x\over x}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos{x\over 2^k}\tag{2}
$$
which is proved in the text.

It's not hard to prove $(1)$.  You just write $\sin x = \sin({x\over3}+{2x\over3})$ and plug away, but I'm having trouble seeing what the generalization is supposed to be.  The only thing I've been able to come up with for the next case is $$
{\sin x\over x}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}
\frac12\left(\cos{x\over4^k}+\cos{3x\over4^k}\right)\tag{3}
$$ 
Again, this isn't hard to prove, but I'm having trouble seeing a pattern in $(1),\ (2),\ \text{and } (3).$  To derive $(3)$ I used the triple angle formula for cosine, and it seems to me that as you go forward you'll need multiple angle formulas for increasing large multiples, so I foresee a lot of complication.

Can you see a formula for the $n=4$ case that is more clearly a generalization of $(1)$ than $(3)$ is?  Or do you know what generalization Kac had in mind?  I'm assuming that he intends for you to come up with a formula for general $n$.

Comment: I see (1) as an average of three evenly spaced cosines, of -2x/3^k, 0, and +2x/3^k.  And I see (3) as an average of four evenly spaced cosines, of -3x/4^k, -x/4^k, +x/4^k, and +3x/4^k.  Does that help?

Comment: @mjqxxxx I think you're onto something.  I remember many years ago, when I first saw Vieta's formula for $2/\pi,$ I proved it by converting to a Riemann sum.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it is a wonderful monograph. For me, it connected many threads together in a very succinct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\,a_n(x) := \sin(nx)/\sin(x)\,$ in terms of $\,\cos(kx).\,$
The first few examples are:
$$ a_2(x) = 2\cos(x), $$
$$ a_3(x) = 1 + 2\cos(2x), $$
$$ a_4(x) = 2\cos(x) + 2\cos(3x), $$
$$ a_5(x) = 1 + 2\cos(2x) + 2\cos(4x), $$
$$ a_6(x) = 2\cos(x) + 2\cos(3x) + 2\cos(5x). $$
The pattern is now obvious.
Thus, the  general infinite product with $\,n>1\,$ is:
$$ \frac{\sin x}x=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac1n a_n\Big(\frac{x}{n^k}\Big). $$