# Generalizing two infinite products for $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ and their 'dual' infinite product

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence, special-functions, closed-form, infinite-product

$\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}$
Throughout, let $m,k$ be positive integers, $x>0$ a real number, and denote $\sinc(z)=\sin(z)/z$ with $\sinc(0)=1$.

A famous result of Euler gives $\sinc(x)$ as an infinite product:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos\left( 2^{-k}x\right)=\sinc(x)
$$Less well-known (although mentioned in *Mathematica*'s documentation for Product) but in a similar vein is
$$
 \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}1-\frac{4}{3}\sin^2(3^{-k}x) = \sinc(x)
$$In fact, each of these are special cases of a more general formula that I found (unfortunately *after* looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864995)):
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} \csc(m^{-k} x)\sin(m^{1-k} x) = \sinc(x)
$$The product term reduces to nice sums depending on the parity of $m$. Further, for even $m$ the product telescopes by double-angle and the result is immediate. Note that the right-hand side does not depend on $m$.

**My question**: what would we get if we switched the roles of $m,k$ in the product? That is, what is the nature of
$$
\prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} \csc(m^{-k} x)\sin(m^{1-k} x) =S_k(x)
$$

The cases $k=1$ and $k\ge 2$ need to be treated separately. For $k=1$, the product term is $\frac{1}{m}\sin (x) \csc \left(\frac{x}{m}\right)$, which approaches $\sinc(x)$ as $m\to \infty$. Thus $S_1(x)=\delta_0(x)$, as for $x\ne 0$ the product diverges to zero. For $k\ge 2$, note that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} m^{2 k-2} \log\left(\frac{\sin \left(x m^{1-k}\right) \csc \left(x m^{-k}\right)}{m}\right) = \frac{-x^2}{6},
$$implying the product converges by comparison with the corresponding series $\sum_{m\ge 1} m^{2-2k}$. Below are pictures of estimates for the $100^{th}$ partial products, for $k=2,\ldots, 6$ and $-6\pi\le x\le 6\pi$.

[image]

Experience has taught me that a closed-form is unlikely but I would nevertheless like to know how $S_k(x)$ depends on $k$, in particular if they are a family of sinc functions as well.

Comment: Probably there is no general closed form, unless the function you made up counts. I tried the logarithm product to sum of logarithms trick with no luck.

Comment: If you accept to make me a favor, could you plot the functions I gave in my answer to compare with your. Being blind I am unable to produce decent plots. Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Using very truncated series $$a_m=\frac1m{\sin \left(x m^{1-k}\right) \csc \left(x m^{-k}\right)}$$
$$a_m=1-\frac{1}{6}  \left(m^2-1\right) m^{-2 k}x^2+\frac{1}{360} \left(3
   m^4-10 m^2+7\right)  m^{-4 k}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Taking logarithms and expanding again
$$\log(a_m)=-\frac{1}{6}  \left(m^2-1\right) m^{-2 k}x^2-\frac{1}{180}
  \left(m^4-1\right) m^{-4 k}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \log(a_m)=-\frac{\zeta (2 k-2)-\zeta (2k)}{6} x^2 -\frac{\zeta (4 k-4)-\zeta
   (4 k)}{180} x^4 +O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\color{red}{\prod_{m=1}^\infty a_m \sim \exp\Bigg[-\frac{\zeta (2 k-2)-\zeta (2k)}{6} x^2 -\frac{\zeta (4 k-4)-\zeta
   (4 k)}{180} x^4+\cdots  \Bigg]}$$ This produces quite well the shape of your curves which in fact are gaussian.